# Ionic Input filed auto create issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

Im used Ionic 3 for a my mobile application, Im tried to create when I  type something on the input filed after want to auto create next filed , but its not work for me, anyone know how to do that correctly

**html**

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="name" right (keyup.enter)="nextfiled()" ></ion-input>
```

**.ts**

```
nextfiled(value: string): void {
    alert('Submitted value: ' + value);
  }
```

Comment: why not use `ionChange`?

Comment: @chaos505 I think OP wants to trigger on pressing Enter

Comment: your function seems to be expecting a value which you are not passing... anything in console?

Comment: @SurajRao ah ok then `(keypress)="eventHandler($event.keyCode)"` would do the trick

Comment: Sir, im not  idea , how to use ion-change for this? any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

**.html**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of textBox">
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="item.one" (keypress)="addTextBox($event.keyCode)"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**.ts**

```
textBox:any = [{one:''}];

addTextBox(ev){
    console.log('isScroll',ev);
    if (ev == 13) {
        this.textBox.push({one:''});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**.html**

`<ion-input (keypress)="eventHandler($event.keyCode)"></ion-input>`

**.ts**

```
eventHandler(keypress) {
    console.log(keypress);
    if(keypress == 13) {
        //run code
    }
}
```